# Adding individuals in owlready for imported ontology and storing individuals

Tags: python, owl, owlready

I have created my ontology in Protege. I have imported it into Python using owlready package.

```
from owlready2 import *
onto = get_ontology("file:////home/PathToOWlfile/file.owl").load()
generator_list = list(onto.classes())
print(generator_list) #To display all classes
base = get_namespace("http://www.URI.org/namespace1#")

obj = base.Dataset('file1') #Assuming Dataset is one of the class in the ontology
obj.hasTitle1.append('fillll') #hasTitle1 and hasTitle2 are two data properties. 
obj.hasTitle2.append('FSA1')
```

How to store this added individuals into the file? I am processing those individual values in python using different function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
with onto: 
   obj = base.Dataset('file1') 
   obj.hasTitle1.append('fillll') 
   obj.hasTitle2.append('FSA1') 
onto.save(file = "temp", format = "ntriples")
```

I was able to store the triples when I add objects with 'with onto'.